# What should we do with one line answers?

Tags: discussion

There are quite a few answers which are one liners (some are also unsourced) or just a link only answer from users who weren't around in a while:

For example:

[Any information about Rabbi Barnett Hasden's "Ner Tamid K" hechsher?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5435/any-information-about-rabbi-barnett-hasdens-ner-tamid-k-hechsher/5436#5436)

[Who asked Rav Moshe about capital punishment?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7098/who-asked-rav-moshe-about-capital-punishment/7101#7101)

[Why should A Capella music be allowed during Sefirah/Three Weeks?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7002/why-should-a-capella-music-be-allowed-during-sefirah-three-weeks/7025#7025)

[Schlisel Challah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7019/schlisel-challah/7020#7020)

[Shabbos Chol Hamoed Pesach Torah reading](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/667/shabbos-chol-hamoed-pesach-torah-reading/6973#6973)

[Is Marijuana Kittnos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6837/is-marijuana-kittnos/6838#6838)

[Wearing a Kittel at the Seder](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6524/wearing-a-kittel-at-the-seder/6535#6535)

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6513/732

Should they be converted to comments?

Comment: Related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1890/472